# Whats the difference between the loadGeoJson and addGeoJson methods on google map v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

They seem to work much in the same way but I can't figure out the difference.

Answer (score 7):

- loadGeoJson takes a URL

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)

> **loadGeoJson**(url:string, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions, callback?:function(Array))
>   Return Value:  None
>   **Loads GeoJSON from a URL, and adds the features to the collection.**

- addGeoJson takes GeoJSON

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)

> **addGeoJson**(geoJson:Object, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions)
>   Return Value:  Array
>   Adds GeoJSON features to the collection. **Give this method a parsed JSON.** The imported features are returned. Throws an exception if the GeoJSON could not be imported.