# Changing Google Maps marker icons through geojson properties

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to plot markers in Google Maps, using geojson files like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Point", 
"coordinates": [-77.76242552657358, -10.749107039737899]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_red.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.76242552657358, -10.749107039737899]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_red.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.7623641788643, -10.7500605616405]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_green.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.77211472346339, -10.728081474512]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_green.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.7614956126977, -10.750647917225699]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_green.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.76185649510131, -10.7516817240557]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_red.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.76185649510131, -10.7516817240557]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_red.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.76242552657358, -10.749107039737899]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_red.png"}}, {"geometry": {"type": 
"Point", "coordinates": [-77.7469388021172, -10.7729040573081]}, "type": 
"Feature", "properties": {"icon": "chart_green.png"}}]}
```

where every marker is represented by a Feature with Point geometry and have a property named "icon" that points to a marker image in the same domain.
Using the following javascript code, I'm able to plot the markers, but all of them have the default red marker image.

```
function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {lat: -12, lng: -77},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var histPlacesCoordinates = map.data.loadGeoJson('hist1.geojson');
    for (var i = 0, length = histPlacesCoordinates.features.length; i < length; i++) {
      var data = histPlacesCoordinates.features[i],
        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.geometry.coordinates[1], data.geometry.coordinates[0]);

      var histPlaces = new google.maps.Marker();
      histPlaces.setStyle({
          position: latLng, 
          map: map,
          icon: data.feature.getProperty("icon")
        });
    }
  }
```

What have I to correct to get each marker drawn with the icon specified in the geojson icon property?

Comment: it should be `icon: data.properties.icon` instead of `icon: data.feature.getProperty("icon")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it working here..Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/4a87k/806/)

```
 function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: -12,
      lng: -77
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  var markerCollection = map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  for (var i = 0, length = markerCollection.length; i < length; i++) {
    var feature = markerCollection[i];
    debugger;
    if (feature.getProperty('icon')) {
      map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        return {
          icon: feature.getProperty('icon')
        };
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Since I am loading geoJson from a variable I have used `addGeoJson` method.
That method will return the feature collection. So we will iterate that and add style to each feature.

```
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return {
      icon: feature.getProperty('icon')
    };
  });
```

Also note that, `loadGeoJson` return value is null. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891327/whats-the-difference-between-the-loadgeojson-and-addgeojson-methods-on-google-ma) answer. so your variable `histPlacesCoordinates` will be undefined or null.

If you are planning to use `loadGeoJson` then you will get the featureCollection inside the callback. You can set the icon in that callBack by iterating that array also.

> loadGeoJson(url:string, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions,
>   callback?:function(Array))